# Формирование xml из базы, более 100 тысяч записей

Tags: xml, php, mysql

Пытаюсь сформировать xml но выборка из базы большая и не получается вывести все значения (база просто падает). 
Как можно с помощью слипа или постепенного сохранения данных в хмл получить полную выборку из базы?

Comment: Я не понял что падает: xml при сохранении или БД при выборке?

Comment: БД при выборке

Comment: Интересно, что есть "большая база". 200-300 мегабайт импортируется достаточно легко. Если объем меньше - проблема либо в коде, либо в слабом хостинге.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если база не может управиться, а выборки нужно делать часто (почему такой большой объем - пока умолчим), то я бы сделал так.

Сами данные  импортировал в что то простое, например csv. Его поддерживает mysql. А на php написал простейший парсер (буквально в десяток строк), который с этого cvs готовил бы xml. При этом я даже не пользовался никакими библиотеками для xml - они бы были дополнительными тормозами. Обычный split + вывод в файл.

Comment: Я не говорил что нужно часто, мне нужно подготовить выгрузку товаров для яндекса.
Собсна хмл для яднекса и нужен. Просто бы еще знать как потом автоматизировать этот процесс с появлением новых товаров и вычетом не актуальных из хмл.

Comment: вопрос в том, осилит ли Яндекс загрузку 100к данных:) Но это отдельная тема.
Как потом в будущем автоматизировать? xml, что бы там не говорили, формат для машин, но не для людей. Поменяются данные - перегенерите по  новой. Такая проблема. Но если нужно ещё и xml разницы делать, также не проблема. Просто нужно хранить старый csv и применить классический алгоритм diff (а если это линукс консоль, то там все уже есть).  А потом на базе дифа и сгенерировать нужный xml.

Answer (score 0):

я бы разбил на множество xml файлов, просто даже с ними работать проще будет.
Если есть в данных время - я бы по времени и разбивал, к примеру помесячно

Comment: Мне необходим 1 хмл

Answer (score -3):

чет ты не так делаешь

я делал подобное с 600000 - за 10 секунд все выгружалось

думаю дело в сервере или кривом коде

надеюсь шаблонизаторы не задействуешь? они все кривые

если php то таймаут нужно большим сделать

и базу нужно оптимизировать, если база кривая (стандартные настройки) то час будет грузить мозги

Comment: А можешь показать пример своей выборки и индексы?